# Why won't my CREATE TABLE statement run without backticks?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This query runs:

```
MariaDB > CREATE TABLE `lines` (`line_id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `page_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -> `file_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    -> `position` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY(line_id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY(page_id) REFERENCES pages(page_id)
    ->     ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

This query does not run:

```
    MariaDB > CREATE TABLE lines (line_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> page_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -> file_name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    -> position varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY(line_id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY(page_id) REFERENCES pages(page_id)
    ->     ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )AUTO_INCREMENT=100; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that          corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines (line_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
page_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
file_name ' at line 1
```

It's the same query except for the backticks. I'm pretty sure that none of these field names are SQL keywords, and so I'm very confused as to why it won't execute without backticks.

I could just be okay with backticks, but I would rather not use them because I don't want to use them for every query I run on this table in the future. I also want syntax to be consistent in the database; there are other tables in the same database that do not require the use of backticks to run queries on them.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: it is `lines` that is a mysql keyword, used with the `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: Here's the list of [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) - there'll be one of these per server version. To investigate this problem, you could have incrementally removed columns until the problem went away - and course table names are as affected by reserved words as column names are.

Comment: Well then... that makes sense. I'll use a different table name. I must have missed it in my pass through the reserve word list. Thanks for the help! (Incredibly fast response, I'll accept the below answer in 5 min when it lets me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lines` is a reserved word in MySQL. That's why we have backticks in the first place. Not using them is like not using quotes in PHP and just relying on the constant not being defined.